# A question on sport commentator sentence

Tags: tenses

This is a quote of a sport commentator Ray Hudson:

> "Waaahhhhh..... are you kidding me? This man is absolutely mainline to pure footballing magic that belongs in a different galaxy altogether that we are living in."

My questions:

- What is the meaning of "mainline"? (I am not even sure if that was the word used)
- Should "belongs in" be "belongs to"?

Video:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qOfdRAnxB1E

Comment: "... different **than** we are living in".  "Belongs in" is current usage when you refer to an appropriate place or position.  Mainline... well, any online dictionary has the answer.

Comment: Ray Hudson's eulogies are perhaps even less mainstream than most song lyrics. Who but he knows? (Though after watching some of the Messi footage, one can understand the need felt for extreme language.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mainline,** a slang referring to injecting heroin into a vein. So the announcer is saying that the player is very much like an express train himself, surging into the top tier of football players. Further, regarding the later portion of the second sentence I submit, "that belongs in a different galaxy altogether that we are living in." should be, "**who** belongs in a different galaxy altogether, **than** we are living in."